# koala, issue with formula in named range

Tags: python, excel, koala

I am trying to use Koala python package for interrogating a relatively intricate excel file. I have a named range that includes a formula, specifically OFFSET. But it seems in the gen_graph() the is_range() check for the named range is mistakenly being flagged True as a range; Since it's an OFFSET and inside the formula a range is being used. Therefore, it is causing an error on the last block of the prepare_pointer() function within the package itself. 
I haven't looked any further to see if there is even functionality to deal with formula named ranges but it would appear not.

Is there a simple way around this? Or do I have to simplify my named ranges in order for this to work?

I actually don't need this formula named range as the worksheets I need to use in the calculation, i.e. for the graph, don't require it. However, when generating the graph even though I have passed list items to "ignore_sheets" it still tries to interrogate ALL the named ranges.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the excel formulas you're using?

Comment: the excel formula is =OFFSET('Sheet1'!$B$4,0,1,1,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$4:$4)-1)...There is a couple things in here that throw it. the named range as a formula and the ranges as a number. It also dosen't like just ex. 'Sheet1'!$A:$A.